# How to get Document Folder in ios device from a Javascript

Tags: javascript, ios, cocos2d-iphone, directory, cocos2d-js

I am integrating a cocos2d-js game into a native iOS app.

At some point I have a  Javascript function inside my ios native app with the following code:

```
var txt = jsb.fileUtils.getStringFromFile("project.json");
```

But my `project.json` is in Document folder instead of in my bundle. So I need to get my Document Folder Path in this Javascript file to have something like this:

```
var myPath = SomeFunctionToGetPath();
var txt = jsb.fileUtils.getStringFromFile("myPath/project.json");
```

Anyone having an idea how I should implement `SomeFunctionToGetPath`?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I had the same issue and was not able to solve it a while ago...

Comment: Hello, were you able to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

`jsb.fileUtils.getWritablePath()` returns the path to Documents folder on iOS.

This is one way you could do it in your code:

```
// First, define the function.
var getFilePath = function(fileName) {
    return jsb.fileUtils.getWritablePath() + fileName;
}

// Then, call it when you need it.
var txt = jsb.fileUtils.getStringFromFile(getFilePath("project.json"));
```